# Run aggregate function in Postgresql stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a question about running built in aggregate functions within a stored procedure on Postgres.

I have a query where I run this function a lot:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(column_name) as max_val,
    MIN(column_name) as min_val,
    (column_name - min_val) / (max_val - min_val) as my_value;
```

I only really care about that final `my_value` parameter, and since I need to run this method for a lot of columns I've been trying to write it as a stored procedure, so I can just run `SELECT get_my_val(column_name);` but am having trouble getting it to work correctly.

Here's along the lines of what I have right now (Note, this is very wrong and does not work):

```
create or replace function get_my_val(col VARCHAR(32))
    RETURNS float AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
            '(' || col || ' - MIN(' || col || ')) / (MAX(' || col || ') - MIN(' || col || '))';
    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I think I'm using `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` incorrectly. Can somebody give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Can you explain this part? (column_name - min_val)

Comment: Sorry that's probably confusing. I want to take the current row's value for that column is and subtract the minimum value of the column from it.

Comment: So if the table has 1,000 rows, you're expecting to get 1,000 rows in the result for each column, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll actually be running a window function in there but figured it's easier to start with a more basic question. Say those 1000 rows are students and 200 are in each grade... The end goal is to get a function that returns the `((GPA current student in grade X) - (MIN(GPA in grade X)) / (MAX(GPA in grade X) - (MIN(GPA in grade X))` for each student.

Comment: No, it's never easier to start with something more basic. You get solutions that don't work for the real situation.